# Jira: how to retrieve a list of field configurations for a project

Tags: jira

Is there a way to retrieve a list of field configurations for a given project from jira database using sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information about JIRA's tables on the [Database Schema](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/database-schema#Databaseschema-Customfieldconfigurationoptions) documentation page. You can also download a pdf there that shows how the tables reference each other.

You probably want to look at these tables:

- fieldconfig
- fieldconfigscheme
- configurationcontext
- project

Comment: Thanks Glenn. The only reason I did not mark your reply as an answer is because I am still checking if it work for me.